# Is it possible to use "Unicode character escape sequences" in verbatim string literals?

Tags: c#, string

I want to put [escapted unicode chars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in verbatim string literals, but I can't figure out how to do it? (maybe I missing somthing simple or its not possible?)

For example I want to do something like this:

```
// Invalid
@"\b hello \u200f world"
// Invalid
```

Where \u200f is interpreted as unicode RTL mark not as string '\\u200f"

I know I can do this this:

```
"\\b hello \u200f world"
```

but verbatim string literals are useful when your string contain lots of '\' chars.

Comment: Clearly the answer is "no". The whole point of verbatim strings is to treat `\\` as a normal character, rather than the start of a special character sequence.

Comment: Given you can do @"""" I didn't think it was so obvious, (ie. thats not 'verbatim' is it?)

Comment: BTW, Visual Studio handles Unicode characters directly in C# strings, both verbatim and non-verbatim. So if it is a character that is supported by whatever font VS displays in, you can copy it from keyboard or online unicode character table, and see it as the actual Unicode letter.

Comment: A workaround, if you can live with a non-constant string, is to use C# 6's string interpolation and insert a normal string containing the escape sequence you need. Otherwise, you'd need to break up your verbatim string into separate sections to allow you to concatenate the string containing the escape sequences into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. To quote [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals.